# traits.api error in python

Tags: python, traits

I downloaded the Enthought Tool Suite through this website: http://code.enthought.com/downloads/.

When I write put this code in the python script:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Str, Int
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from traitsui.menu import OKButton, CancelButton

class SimpleEmployee(HasTraits):
    first_name = Str
    last_name = Str
    department = Str

    employee_number = Str
    salary = Int

view1 = View(Item(name = 'first_name'),
             Item(name = 'last_name'),
             Item(name = 'department'),
             buttons = [OKButton, CancelButton])

sam = SimpleEmployee()
sam.configure_traits(view=view1)
```

I got an error that says:

"ImportError: No module named traits.api "

How do I remedy this?  I don't know what I'm missing.  Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, you will need to compile the Enthought tool suite after downloading, which is not always easy.

I would suggest that you try installing the Enthought Python distribution Free which you can get here:
http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php

That way you should have all the necessary packages installed by default.

**EDIT:**

If you absolutely want to keep the default python distribution, this guy [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) has compiled a list of useful python packages with easy windows installers.

Furthermore there are very complete python distributions out there which come with almost all the scientific package you could need: [PythonXY](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) (although this is only 32bit), then there is the Continuum [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) distribution which has been gaining a lot of ground.

Comment: The Enthought Python distribution does not share packages to my default Python distribution. Or I am doing something wrong...

Comment: No, you are right, the EPD, which is now Canopy, is its own python distribution and it does not play nice with other python distributions innstalled in parallel. I will extend my answer with what I have learnt over time...