# Import traits error/How to compile the Enought Tool Suite so that I can use chaco in Pycharm?

Tags: python, enthought, chaco

Basically, I ran into the error of traits module not showing up. [traits.api error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849997/traits-api-error-in-python)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/Enthought/.idea/Dynamic Plot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, Int
ImportError: No module named 'traits'
```

The answer(hopefully correct) says that the tool suite must be compiled. I want to stay with pycharm. Not sure what compileall would do but it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you install traits?

Comment: @Tim D Through the Enthought Canopy package, I chose its python 2.7 interpreter within pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

There're no problems with PyCharm. Check your imports. If you installed Canopy, then all Enthought libraries should be available through `enthought` package:

```
import enthought.traits
```

Otherwise you should install `etsproxy` or simply install `traits` module via `pip` for direct import:

```
import traits
```